# Cassandra compression codebase

Tags: cassandra, codebase, snappy

I want to know how many bytes are exactly stored on disk when I insert a new column in a Column Family of Cassandra.
My main problem is that I need to know this information when columns are compressed with Snappy, I know the calculation of raw bytes but, due to the variability of the data, I can not properly approximate the compression ratio.
Any information about where to find this amount of bytes in the Cassandra codebase will welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Compression can never give guaranteed compression ratios. The best you can get is an average ratio for sample data.

So get a load of sample data, insert it into a test instance, and measure the disk usage.

You might have data that compresses very poorly with Snappy and actually results in more on-disk usage than storing raw bytes.

When it comes to compression of *your* data there is one and only one rule: MEASURE

Comment: Stephen, I've been testing to measure compression and, indeed, there are certain columns that make the disk usage is lower because RLE compression. You have confirmed what I thought. I guess the only option is to use statistical measures, because I believe that the compression only occur when Cassandra flushes, isn't it?

Thank you again.